# Rotating HTML5 canvas slow?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation

I'm experimenting using rotation on canvas, I have it now so each object has its own rotation. Without them rotating I can get around 400 objects on screen on a very low end computer and nearly 2000 on a normally stocked pc. when I factor in rotation more than 0, the performance drops at least a third!

Why is just changing the rotation slowing it down so much? Is this one of canvases weird hiccups?

I have a global rotation variable and at the beginning of drawing each object I:

```
ctx.rotate(globRot);
```

Comment: which browser you use? "stocked pc" of what CPU grade? any display card?

Comment: On the by normally stocked I mean a decent computer bought within the last year. Nothing amazing, just decent. And the crappy computer is a very crappy computer that probably can't run xp. That's not really important though is it? I just added that for reference to how fast it is before rotation

Comment: In my experience, rotation is not the problem. Take a look at some of the demos/benchmarks of fabric.js — http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/demos/

Comment: Rotation does slow down and hits the performance. There are various substitute approaches, like using image sprite or caching the rotated images...

Answer (score 2):

For individual objects cache the rotations. [Some of my findings](http://www.somethinghitme.com/2010/02/06/dynamic-rotated-sprite-sheet-with-javascripts/).

**[Realtime rotation demo](http://www.somethinghitme.com/projects/rottest/)**

**[Cached rotations demo](http://www.somethinghitme.com/projects/prerotation/)** (note move up using arrows to find the zombies)

Answer (score 1):

I *guess* a lot of time might be spent actually creating and multiplying [the matrix for the transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). If you can (find a way to) cache the transformation when it's not changing, that might help. Maybe.

Comment: That's what I feared. I really hoped to have rotation for everything in this as I wanted a rotating camera

Comment: This was just a hunch anyway. But um -- if you want a rotating camera, then why do would you rotate each object separately instead of rotating (-camera.rotation) before drawing anything? (I might be misunderstanding what you're doing anyway...)

Comment: To emulate a camera rotating I'd have to rotate each object being drawn. In truth that's actually what's being done in any game, it's the object moving and rotating, not the camera. not sure about 3d games

Comment: To emulate a camera rotating around its Z axis (in a 2D game, that's the only axis of rotation anyway) you'd rotate the entire rendering (as it were) matrix of the scene before drawing anything. This way all of the positions and angles of the objects will "naturally" also get rotated correctly. A Jsfiddle demonstrating this: http://jsfiddle.net/jWv8J/2/